# I do need a code filling combo box in front-end from database data in back-end using EJS

Tags: node.js

### This is the back-end

```
   register.get('/register', function (req, res) {
            function get_position(callback) {
                    tempCont.query('SELECT * from `positions`',function (error, results) {     if (error) callback(null);
                    callback(results);
                    console.log("from query = " + results);});
```

### To call the function of query

```
get_position(function (data) {
                if (!!error) {
                    console.log('Error in getting positions to combo box');}
                else {
res.render('register', {positions:positions.id}); } }) })
```

### This is my trial for the front-end

```
    <input type=text list=browsers >
    <datalist id=browsers >
       <% positions.forEach(function(item){ %>
        <option> <%= item %> 
       <%});%>
    </datalist>
```

### The expected result

positions to be appears in the combo box in the web page for user to select a value from it

### The received result

An error: Positions is not defined

Comment: Please expand your question in the description. Additionally, I recommend adding the actual and expected values.

Answer (score 1):

### In back-end

```
 function get_dept(callback) {
                tempCont.query('SELECT * from `positions`', function (error, results) {
                    if (error) callback(null);
                    callback(results);
                });
            }

            get_dept(function (izo) {
                if (!!error) {
                    console.log('Error in getting departments to combo box');
                }
                else {
                    res.render('./register', { errors: null, positions: izo });
                }
            })
```

### In front-end

```
<label>Position</label><br>
<input type=text list=browsers >
<datalist id=browsers >
    <% positions.forEach(function(item){ %>
     <option> <%= item.role_name %> 
    <%});%>
 </datalist>
```